# Kernel Density with vector output and/or possible automation?

Tags: qgis, postgis, r, kernel-density, vectorization

I'm currently working on a project that will have me calculate the kernel density of a number of shapefiles with varying parameters. My current workflow goes like this:

- Import shapefiles in QGIS 2.10.1 from PostGIS 2.2.2
- Run the *Kernel density estimation* command from the SAGA 2.1.2 toolbox
- Vectorize the output with the *r.to.vect* command from the GRASS toolbox
- Export the vector grid back to PostGIS for calculations

The problem is that the *r.to.vect* operation takes about 30-45 minutes per layer, and I will eventually be working with even larger files. Is there a way that I could obtain a vector grid directly instead of a raster? That would save me the useless raster-to-vector transformation. I could work with a solution in PostGIS, QGIS or even R.

Comment: GDAL's `Polygonize (raster to vector)` tool is pretty efficient at vectorizing. Perhaps you could try giving this a go?

Comment: I'll give it a go and I'll see if it speeds up the process.

Comment: For anyone interested, I ended up importing my raster into PostGIS directly and vectorizing it with ST_DumpAsPolygons.

Comment: Thanks for getting back about your problem. Could you please post your comment as an **answer** and accept it by clicking the green-faded tick :)